# Observer in magnetic and electric fields

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

respect an inertial observer O, I have an object of weight m and charge $q$. It is in a electric field $E=(E,0,0)$ constant and a magnetic field $B=(0,0,B)$ constant. I have another observer o' that moves along the y axis with speed $(0,-E/B,0)$ I have to rewrite the dynamics equation respected o' observer and show that it is a cicular uniform motion.

I think the dynamics equation of the observer o' is the same than the other because his movement has acceleration zero but I can't prove is circular.

Comment: Hello! If you want a physical argument, you should consider asking this at physics.stackexchange.com. On the other hand, if you want strictly mathematical help with the change of coordinates, you should provide the dynamical equation you want to transform, any work you've done so far on it, and where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: yes, i have that the dinamic equation of the observer O is $a(t)=q/m(v_2 B+E,-v_1 B,0)$I prefer mathematical solution because Im studying maths XD thanks. Myy problem is that I dont know how to get the velocity or what I need to see is circular because we havent done very much about diferential equations, we have a basic level.

Comment: I think by inertial u mean at rest because otherwise the second observer is also in inertial frame.

Comment: yes, at rest, sorry if my translation is bad, in spanish, is inertial

Comment: Should this be moved to physics.SE?

Comment: @robjohn Yes. it should be. there is not much maths in it.

Comment: @Verod: please add the dynamic equation to the question. Questions should be self-contained and comments should be treated as removable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay , then.In o' frame $$\vec v=-E/B \hat j $$
$$\vec B= B_0  \hat k $$
$$\vec E=E_0   \hat i$$
$$\vec F_B=q(\vec v \hat j \times \vec B \hat k)=qvB \hat i=-qE  \hat i$$
$$\vec F_E=qE  \hat i$$

So, $$\sum\vec F=0$$
So, its same as in frame of observer O as no extra force comes into scene due to relative speed.

Now, if we observe the scenario in O frame ,

$$\vec F_E=qE \hat i$$
So, $$\vec v=qEt \hat i$$
$$\vec F_B=q(\vec v\times \vec B)=q(qEtB)\ \perp \hat v\ in\ X-Y \ plane$$
Now as $V$ and $F_b$
 are $\perp$ then the motion is a circular due to $F_B$ but the drag due to $\vec E$ will distrott the circular motion and particle will move in a complicated path.

A very-very$\times \infty$ rough diagram of path:[image]

The radius goes on increasing due to increasing speed and particle is dragged to +ve direction of X-axis.